# ItemControl style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

When I create ItemsControl and grouping it, for example:

```
<CollectionViewSource x:Key="items" Source="{Binding Items}">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <swd:PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="User"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
</CollectionViewSource>

<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource items}}"
    <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"</TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
    </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <TextBlock Text="{Binding item}"></TextBlock>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
          <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

Now, with default stlye it's looks somthing like this:

```
Group name
     item1, item2, item3 etc.
```

But I don't want items in new line, I want it in the same line with group name, like this:

```
Group name item1, item2, item3 etc.
```

How to do it? I know that probably need to create Style but I don't know which property excatly I need to change.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to overwrite the `Template` of the `GroupItem` using the `GroupItem.ContainerStyle`.